# Where can I find variable values while debugging JSPs?

Tags: jsp, intellij-idea

When debugging a JSP like the following, in IntelliJ:

```
<c:when test="${not useBuiltScripts}">
    <script src="/static/js/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/modernizr/modernizr.js?v=1.7" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/simpleFade.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/jcarousel/dist/jquery.jcarousel.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/prettyCheckboxes.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/sr-beauty-tips/jquery.bt.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/functions.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</c:when>
```

where should I be looking to find the current value of `useBuiltScripts`, when I have a breakpoint on that line?

I've tried mousing over, to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried adding a watch point?

Comment: I would... but what would I watch?